# PSPACE-completeness of DFA intersection problem

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, automata, finite-automata, space-complexity

Let some deterministic finite automata be given. There is a problem of determining whether the intersection of these DFA is empty, and I want to show its PSPACE-completeness.

It seems to me that I understand, why this problem lies in PSPACE: if $ n_1,\dots, n_k $ are the numbers of states, then one can take the product of these DFA and get that if there is a recognisable string, then there is a recognisable string of length $ \le n_1\dots n_k$. Then we can non-deterministically guess this string and use Savitch theorem.

So, the question is, how to prove PSPACE-hardness? Should I reduce any given TM to this problem, or maybe some known problem like QBF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof that the problem is in PSPACE is not quite correct. The problem is that the product $n_1 \cdots n_k$ is not bounded by a polynomial in the input length $n_1 + \dots + n_k$. The correct way to do it is to directly apply Savitch's theorem to the NPSPACE machine that nondeterministically guesses a path through the product graph. The difference is that, while an accepting path can indeed be as long as $n_1 \dots n_k$, the machine only guesses one symbol at a time and *never stores the entire input string in memory*, so we stay within the polynomial space limit.

---

It is a well-known fact that this problem is PSPACE-hard, but the only proof that I am aware of is not particularly trivial. I believe the first proof was given in:

> Dexter Kozen. [Lower Bounds for Natural Proof Systems](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kozen/Papers/LowerBounds.pdf). FOCS 1977: 254-266.

The proof involves constructing a mess of DFAs which collectively enforce all the necessary constraints to require that any string in the intersection language is a trace of the execution of a polynomial space Turing machine that leads to an accepting configuration.